# workaround to serialize a java audioClip

Tags: java, audio, serialization, serializable

I need to serialize an AudioClip to a file, as part of another data 
structure, unfortunately the AudioClip doesn't seem to be serializable.  Is there an 
object I could serialize as a proxy.  Something that I could move back 
and forth between AudioClip as necessary?

I tried this simple code/class

```
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class RandomClass implements Serializable {

    private AudioClip myAudioClip;
    private int RandomInteger;
    private String RandomString;


    public RandomClass(String soundpath){
        soundpath = soundpath.replace(" ", "%20");
        soundpath = soundpath.replace("\\", "/");
        try{
            URL sound = new URL("file:/"+soundpath);
            myAudioClip = JApplet.newAudioClip(sound);
        }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void serializeMe(){

        try{

             FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("c:\\serialized.ser");
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);   
             oos.writeObject(this);
             oos.close();

        }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
        }
   }


    public static void main(String args[]){

        RandomClass d = new RandomClass("C:\\audioclip.wav");
        d.serializeMe();
    }
}
```

I get a java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.applet.AppletAudioClip

What I actually want is the audioclip to be saved along with other member Objects or types in a single serialized file. So that whenever I reload the file (which actually gonna contain an arrayList of these RandomClass objects) I get every data member of each of these RandomClass objects without the need to keep the original audioclip on the harddrive (i.e I want to create some kind of archive of objects that contain audioclip as part of their data members). I also need to be able to play the audioClips without the need to save them back to *.wav onto the harddrive. Just like VLC can play a whole playlist in a zip file without having to extract each clip.
Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: @EJB Well, I also need to be able to play the audio clip after reload and I don't know how to go from bytes array to audioClip. I don't wanna have to save to *.wav the bytes before being able to play the clip

Comment: Why not? That's all it is.

Comment: @EJP I did some searching and end up on this [image to byte array](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-image-to-byte-array-convert-byte-array-to-image/). I transposed the second example by replacing BufferedImage with AudioInputStream inputStream and ImageIO.write() by AudioSystem.write() it doesn't seem to work. To tell you the truth I am not sure I know how to go from AudioStream to byte array.

Comment: Hold the phone. The AudioInputStream must have *started* with a byte stream in a file. That's what you want to send.

Answer (score 0):

GOTCHA!!! I finally found the way to do it. Like EJP said **the key part is to save in a byte array**. The only solution I come up with so far is by using the technique [to convert a file to a byte array](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-a-file-to-byte-array-then-convert-byte-array-to-a-file/) in addition to sun.audio.AudioPlayer and sun.audio.AudioStream each time I want to play the sound file.

Here is an example class:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

public class SoundSerializer implements Serializable {

    private byte[] buf;
    private int randomInteger =0;
    private String randomString = "";

    public SoundSerializer() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\soundFile.wav");

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        buf = new byte[1024];

        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
            //Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this byte array output stream.
            System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
        }

        buf = bos.toByteArray();
    }


    /**
     *fonction to test the sound after deserialization
     */
    public void playSound(){
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
        AudioStream audioStream = null;
        try {
            audioStream = new AudioStream(is);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SoundSerializer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
    }
}
```

P.S. 
I tried a combo using AudioInputStream + AudioSystem.write() to save to an array (ByteArrayOutputStream --> byte[]) it didn't work. Check [image to byte Array](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-image-to-byte-array-convert-byte-array-to-image/) and transpose with those Audio oriented Classes. Working on a solution...